# .map is returning only the last element of array React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array-map

I'm creating a blog type app with cloud firestore just as a project to learn some stuff. However I'm having an issue where only the last element of my state array, 'blogs', is being returned inside of the .map method.

Any help with this is appreciated, thanks!

```
const [blogs, setBlog] = useState([]);
const fetchBlogs = async () => {
    const response = await getDocs(collection(db, "blog posts"));
    let postArray = [];
    response.docs.forEach((blogpost) => {
        postArray.push(blogpost.data());
    });
    console.log(postArray)
    postArray.forEach(post => {
        setBlog([...blogs, post]);
    });
}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchBlogs();
}, []);

return (
    <ul className="posts-container">
       { blogs.map((blog) => { 
           console.log(blog); //this outputs each of the individual posts, but only the last is displayed as an <li>
           return ( <li key={blog.title}>{blog.title}</li> )
        })}
    </ul>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to put the response in your state without doing the `forEach()`

```
setBlog(postArray);
```

Or even (depending on data structure)

```
const [blogs, setBlog] = useState([]);

const fetchBlogs = async () => {
    const response = await getDocs(collection(db, "blog posts"));
    setBlog(response.data); // set to whatever you need
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchBlogs();
}, []);

return (
    <ul className="posts-container">
       { blogs.map((blog) => { 
            return <li>( <li key={blog.title}>{blog.title}</li> )
          }
       )}
    </ul>
);
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked for me great, thanks a lot! looks like i need to get back to reading useState docs!

Comment: @StevieWonder glad I could help! Read about fetching data with React, you probably use `axios` so look for some examples online

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```js
postArray.forEach(post => {
  setBlog([...blogs, post]);
});
```

Try doing this:

```js
setBlog(postArray);
```

I am not sure as to what exactly happens, but this seems like the most suspicious piece in your code.

Comment: Correct! thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the blog post twice, try it this way

```js
const fetchBlogs = async () => {
    const response = await getDocs(collection(db, "blog posts"));
    setBlog([...blogs, ...response.docs.map(blogpost => blogpost.data())])
}

useEffect(() => fetchBlogs(), []);
```

Comment: This also fixed the problem thanks a lot! However i found the marked correct approach a little neater